# NaN% in NARX net MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I am using Nonlinear Autoregressive Network with External Input (NARX) for training and testing my data. But I am getting NAN% while computing MAPE.The err and Actual data shows NAN% in the last row as shown in:
[image]

```
Training inputs=35064x8
Training targerts=35064x1
```

Now, I am testing on trained network `net`

```
Test inputs=17544x8
Test inputs=17544x1
```

I am using the delays

```
% Create a Nonlinear Autoregressive Network with External Input
inputDelays = 1:1;
feedbackDelays = 1:1;
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = narxnet(inputDelays,feedbackDelays,hiddenLayerSize);
```